# PostgreSQL aggregate windows recursively

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a series of `Event`s which are produced by different users over time.

How can I aggregate this series by events that are close each other. Two events are close (in the same window) if:

```
    b.user = a.user
and b.time >= a.time
and b.time - a.time <= interval '1 month'
```

This is a recursive condition. For example, the following dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE pg_temp.Data
    ("event" int, "user" int, "date" date, "value" int)
;

INSERT INTO pg_temp.Data
    ("event", "user", "date", "value")
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2017-01-01', 5),
    (2, 1, '2017-01-07', 3),
    (3, 1, '2017-02-09', 2),
    (4, 1, '2017-03-12', 4),
    (5, 1, '2017-04-03', 7),
    (6, 1, '2017-05-01', 6),
    (7, 2, '2017-01-05', 9),
    (8, 2, '2017-01-12', 1),
    (9, 2, '2017-03-24', 6)
;


select * from pg_temp.Data
```

should be reduced to something like:

```
[
    {
        "init": "2017-01-01",
        "latest": "2017-01-07",
        "events": [
            1,
            2
        ],
        "user": 1,
        "value": 8
    },
    {
        "init": "2017-02-09",
        "latest": "2017-02-09",
        "events": [
            3
        ],
        "user": 1,
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "init": "2017-03-12",
        "latest": "2017-05-01",
        "events": [
            4,
            5,
            6
        ],
        "user": 1,
        "value": 17
    },
    {
        "init": "2017-01-05",
        "latest": "2017-01-12",
        "events": [
            7,
            8
        ],
        "user": 2,
        "value": 10
    },
    {
        "init": "2017-03-24",
        "latest": "2017-03-24",
        "events": [
            9
        ],
        "user": 2,
        "value": 6
    }
]
```

Where `init` and `latest` are the window's time range and `value` is the sum of values in the window.

Note that events `6` and `4` are more than one month apart, but they've been aggregated into the same group because event `5` is in between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT min(date) AS init,
       max(date) AS latest,
       array_agg(event) AS events,
       "user",
       sum(value) AS value
FROM (SELECT event,
             "user",
             date,
             value,
             count(grp_start)
                OVER (PARTITION BY "user" ORDER BY date) session_id
      FROM (SELECT event,
                   "user",
                   date,
                   value,
                   CASE
                      WHEN date
                         > lag(date, 1, timestamp '-infinity')
                              OVER (PARTITION BY "user" ORDER BY date)
                           + INTERVAL '1 month'
                      THEN 1
                   END grp_start
            FROM data
           ) tagged
     ) numbered
GROUP BY "user", session_id
ORDER BY "user", init;
```

This will result in:

```
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────┬──────┬───────┐
│        init         │       latest        │ events  │ user │ value │
├─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────┼──────┼───────┤
│ 2017-01-01 00:00:00 │ 2017-01-07 00:00:00 │ {1,2}   │    1 │     8 │
│ 2017-02-09 00:00:00 │ 2017-02-09 00:00:00 │ {3}     │    1 │     2 │
│ 2017-03-12 00:00:00 │ 2017-05-01 00:00:00 │ {4,5,6} │    1 │    17 │
│ 2017-01-05 00:00:00 │ 2017-01-12 00:00:00 │ {7,8}   │    2 │    10 │
│ 2017-03-24 00:00:00 │ 2017-03-24 00:00:00 │ {9}     │    2 │     6 │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────┴──────┴───────┘
(5 rows)
```

A word af advice: it is a good idea *not* to use column names like `user` that are reserved words. If you forget to use them inside double quotes, surprising things will happen (try it out).